# How to replace value of column in a row with other columns in same row

Tags: oracle

How to replace value of column in a row with other columns in same row below are the sample db data and output which is required  any help would be appreciated.

Data in DB:

[image: Data in DB]

I tried using if else but not able to solve it below is the sample if else code

```
if ((@adrln1 is null) and (@adrln2 is not null or @adrln3 is not null or @adrstc is not null or @adrpsz is not null or @ctry_name is not null))
{
    publish data
     where adrnam = @adrnam
       and adrln1 = @adrln2
       and adrln2 = @adrln3
       and adrln3 = @adrstc
       and adrstc = @adrpsz
       and adrpsz = @ctry_name
       and ctry_name = ''
}
```

Required Result:

[image: Required Result]

Comment: check `decode` or `case` statement. Please post your data as text not as screenshots

Comment: Please [post formatted text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Are you trying to update the data in the table, or just modify it when querying? Why does CZE move all the way across to `adrln1`, but NLD only goes as far as `adrstc` - not to `adrln3`? Please include a clear explanation of what you are doing and the rules involved. (Your sample code isn't SQL - are you actually doing this in Oracle, or Excel?)

Comment: Also, you've tagged this as `[oracle]` but the code snippet clearly isn't SQL. Are you expecting a SQL solution? If not you'll need to indicate what programming language you're using.